# Angular blank option selected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select

I'm banging my head against the wall on this one.

I have an array of objects that will be used to populate a select drop down:

```
CardCount = [{"ClientId": "0010", "Description": "0010 (206 Members)"}, {"ClientId": "0051", "Description": "0051 (1 Member)"}, ........]
```

When I attempt to use ng-options, the value of the option is set to the index, not to the ClientId as desired. To get the value in each option to be the ClientId, I have to use a ng-repeat in the options. Here is my html:

```
<select ng-model="CurrentClient">
    <option ng-repeat="item in CardCount" value="{{item.ClientId}}">{{item.Description}}</option>
</select>
```

Initially, all is well, the select and options are generated correctly, and the first option is correct. Now, when a certain button is clicked somewhere else on the page, it becomes necessary to recreate this select and options with a smaller array of similar objects. However, doing so creates a blank option with a value of "? string:0010 ?". This is the option that is selected. Again, I cannot use ng-options to correct this problem because doing so doesn't set the value attribute in the option tags correctly. So, I added this to the option tag:

```
<option ng-repeat="item in CardCount" value="{{item.ClientId}}" ng-selected="CurrentClient == item.ClientId">{{item.Description}}</option>
```

Now, that does mark the correct option as selected. However, the drop down still shows the blank option. Here's the rendered html:

```
<select ng-model="CurrentClient">
    <option value="? string:0010 ?"></option>
    <option value="0010" selected="selected">0010 (206 Members)</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, it sets the correct option to selected. However, it sets it to `selected="selected"`, and not just `selected`. When I inspect element and change `selected="selected"` to `selected` (remove the equals and everything after it), the drop down then correctly displays the correctly selected option.

Again, initially the select and options work great. The problem seems to happen only after the array that the select is created with is changed. How can I get this select and options working correctly after I change the array, and not show that first blank option?

Thanks!

Comment: use `ng-repeat="item in CardCount track by item.ClientId"`

Comment: @pankajparkar: I just tried that. That does work. However, I am limited to using the item.ClientId in the option text as well. So, when I do this: `<option ng-repeat="item in CardCount track by item.ClientId">{{item.Description}}</option>`, it sets the value as the description. I know, weird. When I do `{{item.ClientId}}` in the option text between the tags, the option value is then set correctly. It seems the value and the text must match.

Comment: change code to `<option ng-repeat="item in CardCount track by item.ClientId" value="item.ClientId" ng-bind="item.Description"></option>`

Comment: @pankajparkar: That works, thanks! To be clear, the exact code that worked for me is: `<option ng-repeat="item in CardCount track by item.ClientId" value="{{item.ClientId}}">{{item.Description}}</option>`

Comment: Kindly do voteup or mark answer as correct. Thanks.

Comment: I made a post about it here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949621/angular-js-ng-model-on-select-ghost-option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed you option element to set value by default.

```
<option ng-repeat="item in CardCount track by item.ClientId" 
value="{{item.ClientId}}">{{item.Description}}</option>
```

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ng-options is definitely the way to go:

```
<select ng-model="selected.ClientId" ng-options="it.ClientId as it.Description for it in clientList">
    <option value="">-</option>
</select>
```